# Use higher-order functions instead of explicit recursion

Tags: function, haskell, higher-order-functions

I want to write a function `f` that converts a binary list to an integer, like:

```
f :: [Integer] -> Integer
f [] = 0
f list = (last list) * 2^(length list -1) + f (init list)
```

For example, in `f [1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0] = 79`, the first list element represents 2^0 and the last list element represents 2^7.

Can I write this function with higher-order functions instead of with explicit recursion?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with `foldl`.

Comment: Thats what i thought, but how i can handle (length list -1) in foldl ?

Comment: Forget about exponentiation and `length`. Think `abcd = 1*d + 2*c + 2*2*b + 2*2*2*a = 1*d + 2*(c + 2*(b + 2*a)))`.

Comment: @Sambud_Ger: you don't need the length, if you each time multiply with two, and add the value, eventually you obtain `2^n`.

Comment: molbdnilo refers to [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: @sambud_Ger: you can also use `foldr` here, since here the first element is the *least* signifiacant*.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the order of your list is unfortunate for foldl, but you can pass the exponent along like so:

```
intvalueOfList = fst . foldl f (0,1) 
   where f (acc,exp) e = (acc+e*exp, exp*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`foldr :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) which uses a "folding" function that takes an element and the accumulator. The accumulator conceptually runs right-to-left over the list. You can thus each time souble the accumulator and then add the value of the element:

```
f :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a
f = foldr g 0
    where g x acc = …
```

where you still need to fill in `g`.